# AM/PM comparison in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, comparison

```
$star_time = "2015-05-15 09:30 PM";
$end_time  = "2015-05-15 09:40 AM";
```

when comparing these two date/time it's showing that $end_time bigger than $star_time when $star_time actually is bigger because the time at night while $end_time in the morning!!!

why the comparison disregard AM/PM ?

thank you

```
if($star_time > $end_time)
echo $star_time .">". $end_time;
else
echo $star_time ."<". $end_time;
```

Comment: Which code do you use to compare these two dates?

Comment: added the comparison code to my question, thx

Comment: You should use `strtotime` instead.

Comment: Looks like your comparing two strings, to convert to date object see Dave Chen's comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables are strings and you are using the `>` operator for comparison.

You need to convert your strings into a timestamp and then do the comparison.

[strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php) is your friend or the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php).

Answer (score 2):

Comparing the two blank strings as you do here, won't do what you expect it do to and it is not how you compare two dates. Because your [strings gets converted to an integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) if you compare them, so if you do:

```
echo $star_time + 0;  //2015
echo $end_time + 0;   //2015
```

You will see in which integer your strings gets converted. And that's simply everything until a non numerical value (in your case the dash: `-`).

Means your condition looks like this:

```
if(2015 > 2015)
```

And 2015 isn't bigger than 2015. So you see:

1. This doesn't do what you want
2. This is also not how you compare dates, because as you can see the dates doesn't get compared correctly

Just create a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object and compare the timestamps from both dates, .e.g

```
<?php

    $star_time = "2015-05-15 09:30 PM";
    $end_time  = "2015-05-15 09:40 AM";

    $start = new DateTime($star_time);
    $end = new DateTime($end_time);

    if($start->getTimestamp() > $end->getTimestamp())
        echo $star_time .">". $end_time;
    else
        echo $star_time ."<". $end_time;

?>
```

output:

```
2015-05-15 09:30 PM > 2015-05-15 09:40 AM
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote, so I can improve my answer.

Comment: i don't know who gave you downvote, thank you for your answer

Comment: @user4907354 You're welcome. (Also expanded my explanation what actually happens if you compare them as plain strings)

Comment: @user4907354 May I know what is so much better in the other answer, that you accept it?

Comment: @Rizier123 You don't need to compare the timestamps. DateTime objects are directly comparable, so you can just do `if($start > $end){}`. http://3v4l.org/ZbJbZ, although this may break on PHP < 5.3.

Comment: @vascowhite yes, that's correct for DateTime objects, but I used the timestamp for the logic of it, that you compare the seconds (integers) together and not strings. So to also show some similarity to `strtotime()`, which also can be used to get the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing strings, you should compare integers

```
if (strtotime($star_time) > strtotime($end_time)) {
   echo $star_time .">". $end_time;
}
else {
   echo $star_time ."<". $end_time;
}
```